# SMTPAuthentication error when sending confirmation email in Django

Tags: python, django

Getting the error message

> SMTPAuthenticationError at /accounts/signup/teacher/ (530, b'Must
>   issue a STARTTLS command first')

when trying to test the signup process in my django app. What should happen is that a user who signs in should receive a confirmation email after signing up.

Here are my settings

```
EMAIL_BACKED = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USER_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '***@***.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '***'
```

I am using privateemail from namecheap to send the confirmation emails

Comment: Did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31872336/6699447)?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM but am I not using TLS by enabling EMAIL_USER_TLS ?

Comment: It's `EMAIL_USE_TLS` without `R`.